# Creating docx paragraphs from strings array

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, docx

I have in document placeholder with some text. This text consists from several strings, splitted by "`<line>`". How can I replace this text witha scoupe of paragraphs, each containing only one string?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. It was only necessary to break the string and for each string create a paragraph with formatting, otherwise the elements are created as OpenXmlUnknownElement.

```
   XDocument customXml = GenerateXmlForReport(report);
            String customXmlId = AddCustomXml(document, customXml);
            DataBind(document, customXml, customXmlId);
            document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.GetFirstChild<SdtBlock>().RemoveAllChildren();
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(report.ReportTextBody, "</line>");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "BodyText" };
                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
                RunFonts runFonts1 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Arial", HighAnsi = "Arial" };
                paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(runFonts1);
                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);
                RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
                RunStyle runStyle1 = new RunStyle() { Val = "PlaceholderText" };

                runProperties1.Append(runStyle1);
                Run run = new Run();
                Text txt = new Text(line);
                run.Append(txt);
                p.Append(run);
                document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.GetFirstChild<SdtBlock>().Append(p);

            }
```